# Django admin panel doesn't work

Tags: python, django

Could someone explain me please what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to enable admin panel in Django 1.2. But the link http://mysite.com/admin raises 404 error, and the link http://mysite.com raises an error like this:

```
    TypeError at /

list objects are unhashable

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://mysite/index.wsgi/
Django Version:     1.2.4
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

list objects are unhashable

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.5/re.py in _compile, line 230
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version:     2.5.5
Python Path:    ['/usr/local.20100210/lib/python2.5/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Genshi-0.6-py2.5.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Babel-0.9.5-py2.5.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Pygments-1.4-py2.5.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/pytz-2010o-py2.5.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Trac-0.12.1-py2.5.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/IniAdmin-0.2-py2.5.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/TracAccountManager-0.2.1dev-py2.5.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.5-freebsd-8.2-RELEASE-amd64.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python25.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/plat-freebsd8', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/PIL', '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages', '/home/casf58/www/site2/cgi-bin/']
Server time:    Tue, 11 Jun 2013 20:52:41 +0400
```

This is the empty test project which works fine on local machine. But it doesn't work at hosting. Of course, I uncommented all the necessary lines in urls.py and setiings.py and checked it several times. If I comment them back, the Django Welcome page is displayed. 
Still can't find a solution in google...

Python v.2.5. Project uses wsgi_mod.

Changes in settings.py:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Example:
    # (r'^mysite/', include('mysite.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)
)
```

Comment: can you show the settings you modified?

Comment: I mean __show__ the changed settings.

Comment: I added the changes in my post above.

Comment: I can't tell if you showed us the urls.py *before* you changed it, or if you didn't actually comment out those lines

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose your url pattern in `()`

```
 (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Try this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Example:
    # (r'^mysite/', include('mysite.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: Enclosing pattern in brackets causes "Page not found (404)" error.

Comment: most likely there is another match. Is that your entire urls.py ?

Comment: Yes, it is. This is a simple project from tutorial.

Comment: I was just reading somewhere, may be a reinstall of django would help ?

Comment: Unfortunately it's impossible because the project is located at the hosting now. And there's no virtual environment to make it possible to install another version of Django.

Comment: The Traceback stops here: /usr/local/lib/python2.5/re.py in _compile

Comment: Seems it's a Python bug. On version 2.7.5 and Django ver. 1.5.1 all works fine.

Comment: Well, it could be a corrupt installation in my opinion, because, I have used all versions from django from 1.1 to 1.5, and Python 2.5+ and never faced this issue.